# Kernel Image Processing with a buffered image

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

So I have a given 3 by 3 array mask[][] and a buffered image. I must loop through the position[row][column] of the buffered image, and I must place the middle pixel of the mask to the current buffered image position. Then for each color component , I must multiply the value of the color component in the image that falls under the mask to the corresponding mask value, and add all nine values together. Lastly I combine the three color values to get the RGB color of the pixel.

Comment: Sounds like all you are missing is a programmer.

Comment: Your probably looking for the built-in [ConvolveOp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ConvolveOp.html).

Comment: I would like to do it without using the ConvolveOp. I understand how to loop through it, but am unsure of how to deal with the color components.

Comment: You have to treat the different color components separately.